# NodeJS multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I am writing a web scraper that makes multiple requests based on a list that looks like this

```
 1. Category1
    1a. categoryItem1
    1b. categoryItem2
 2. Category2
    2a. categoryItem1
    2b. categoryItem2
    2c. categoryItem3
 3. Category3
    3a. categoryItem1
```

Both `Category` and `categoryItem` are links. **Only 1 `Category` can be expanded at a time.** The amount of `Categories` and `categoryItems` can change so I don't know the exact amount before hand.

I am gathering the data on each `categoryItem` page to be saved in a `json` that looks like this

```
{
    "Category1": [
        "categoryItem1: {
            // Details saved here
        },
        "categoryItem2: {
            // Details saved here
        }
    ],
    "Category2": [
        "categoryItem1: {
            // Details saved here
        },
        "categoryItem2: {
            // Details saved here
        },
        "categoryItem3: {
            // Details saved here
        }
    ],
    "Category3": [
        "categoryItem1: {
            // Details saved here
        }
    ]
}
```

The only thing left for me is to figure out how to make this **act** synchronous

1. Get the opening page
2. Open each `Category` list
3. Open each `categoryItem` details page

[**THIS**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) was the web scraper tutorial that I followed, if you would like to know. Due to async calls I don't know when the very last page is parsed, so here is the structure of the script

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {

    globalJSON = {};

    baseUrl = 'http://...';

    // 1.) open page with list
    request.get(baseUrl, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            // select the list
            $('#categoryListSelector').filter(function () {
                var data = $(this);

                var listItem = data.find('#listItemSelector');

                var expansionLink = listItem.find('a').attr('href'); // <a href=""></a>
                var category = listItem.find('font').text();

                // Save category to global json
                globalJSON[category] = [];

                // 2.) Expand the list by opening expansionLink
                request.get(baseUrl + expansionLink, function (error, response, html) {
                    if (!error) {
                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                        // Select the sub items of each list item
                        $('#subItem selector').filter(function () {
                            var data = $(this);

                            var categoryItemPageLinkElement = data.find('a');

                            var categoryItemName = categoryItemPageLinkElement.text();
                            var categoryItemLink = $(categoryItemPageLinkElement).attr('href');

                            if (typeof categoryItemLink != "undefinded" && categoryItemLink != null && categoryItemLink != "") {

                                categoryItemObject = {}; // { categoryItemName: categoryItemDetails }
                                categoryItemDetails = {};

                                // 3.) Open the categoryItem page to start gathering data
                                request.get(baseUrl + categoryItemLink, function (error, response, html) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                                        // GATHER and save data here

                                        // Done gathering data save to global json
                                        categoryItemObject[categoryItemName] = categoryItemDetails;
                                        globalJSON[category].push(categoryItemObject);

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(globalJSON, null, 4), function (err) {
                console.log('File successfully written!');
            });
            res.send(globalJSON);

        }//END if(!error)
    });

})//END app.get()

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

### Update

I did get my issue solved with some help from the feller below, and this is what I came up with. Now, there might be a better way, feel free to let me know.

Basic Layout

```
Promise.all(categoriesArr.map(categoryObj => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        request.get(baseUrl + categoryObj.categoryItemLink, (error, response, html)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }

            //build an array of ALL the categoryItemLinks

            return resolve(res, html);
        });
}))).then(function(statesArray) {

        Promise.all(allCategoryItems.map(categoryItemObject => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            request.get(baseUrl + categoryItemObject.categoryItemPageLink, (error, response, html)=>{
                if(error){
                    return reject(error);
                }
                // Gather Data and put into dataJson

                return resolve(response, html);
            });
        }))).then(function(data) {

            // Do finishing stuff

        }).catch(/*error*/);

}).catch(/*error*/);
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {

    categoriesArr = [];
    allCategoryItems = [];

    dataJson = {}; // Global json to hold all the data

    baseUrl = 'http://www.blahblah.org';

    request.get(baseUrl, function(error, response, html) {
            if (!error) {

                var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                $('#categorySelector').filter(function() {
                    var data = $(this);

                    var categoryItemLink = data.find('a').attr('href');

                    categoriesArr.push({
                        "categoryItemLink": categoryItemLink
                    });

                });

                Promise.all(categoriesArr.map(categoryObj => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                    request.get(baseUrl + categoryObj.categoryItemLink, (error, response, html)=>{
                        if(error){
                            return reject(error);
                        }

                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                        $('#categoryItemSelector').filter(function() {
                            var data = $(this);
                            var categoryItemPageLinkElement = data.find('a');
                            var categoryItemPageLink = $(categoryItemPageLinkElement).attr('href');

                            if(typeof categoryItemPageLink != "undefinded" && categoryItemPageLink != null && categoryItemPageLink != "") {

                                allCategoryItems.push({
                                    "categoryItemPageLink": categoryItemPageLink
                                });

                            }
                        });

                        return resolve(res, html);
                    });
                }))).then(function(statesArray) {

                    Promise.all(allCategoryItems.map(categoryItemObject => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                        request.get(baseUrl + categoryItemObject.categoryItemPageLink, (error, response, html)=>{
                            if(error){
                                return reject(error);
                            }
                            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                            // Gather Data and put into dataJson

                            return resolve(response, html);
                        });
                    }))).then(function(data) {

                        // Do finishing stuff

                    }).catch(/*error*/);

                }).catch(/*error*/);

            }//END if(!error)
    });

})//END app.get()

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()`, so something like:

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    request.get(url, (err, res, html)=>{
        if(err){
            return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(res, html);
    });
}))).then(/*success*/).catch(/*error*/);
```

In that code, the `.then()` executes after all requests have come back with a response.

Comment: Thing is I don't know how many urls there are...the amount of urls can change

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 this doesn't care how many urls there are. As long as the urls are in an array, and you map that array, returning an array of promises, one for each url, it'll be fine.

Comment: This does require Node >= v4.X though, or a promise library.

Comment: Right, I get that, but I would have to put the urls in the array before hand, like maybe I make the first request and gather all the category links in an array. Then iterate using the `promise.all` on that list. For each request for each category gather all the categories' `categoryItem`'s and put them in a list. Then somehow use `promise.all`, because I would know all the `categories` and all the `categoryItem` links

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 sounds like you should be putting those in arrays to begin with :)

Comment: inside the `.then()` can I do this `.then(function(res, html) { /* do stuff with the html param*/ })`

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 yup, think of it as a callback.

Comment: Okay So I figured it out and it works great. I edited the answer with an Update section to show what I came up with